# Sitecore error - Required License Missing: Runtime

Tags: sitecore-client

I getting error when running a sitecore 9.0 instance.Error is "Required License Missing:Runtime".Please provide Any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for your Sitecore website to work, you need to have a valid license file.

License files can only be obtained by spending the money or getting one from Sitecore if you are a Sitecore partner.

Few month ago Sitecore Developer Trial Program was launched and you can receive a trial license for 60 days free of charge (https://www.sitecore.com/getting-started/developer-trial).

Default license is located on c:\inetpub\wwwroot\yoursite\App_Data\license.xml.

Do you have such a license?